# reliable virtual desktop environment for Amazon EC2 Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, remote-desktop

I have an ubuntu 13.04 instance in the Amazon EC2 Cloud.  I am trying to run some java programs on the server that require a GUI desktop environment.  I need just 1 desktop instance to connect to via remote desktop.  I would like just to be able to re-connect every time, and when I disconnect I would like the instance to keep running while I am not connected, just as if I walked away from a desktop computer.  Of course it should be possible to formally "log off" of the instance, and that would end my desktop session, but many times I need the programs to continue to run while I am not physically connected.

I am wondering if any of you has had any experience with this, if so, what should I try?

Right now I have the LXDE desktop running, and I can connect via xrdp.  The problems I am getting, the BIG problem, is that the desktop environment is very unstable.  Many times I disconnect without notice and cannot reconnect.  Also I notice that the server sometimes just shuts down my java program automatically (I am still trying to figure out the exact cause).  For example just now I logged on to the LXDE and fired up my java program.  minutes later the RDP disconnected and now I am unable to re-connect.  I will prob have to reboot the instance.

Another problem, but not nearly as serious as the first, is that every time I re-connect via XRDP (assuming it hasn't crashed) it automatically starts a new desktop session instead of re-connecting to the old one.  It isn't a big deal, I can always find the ID of the previous session and edit the config file via ssh to force a connection to that ID, but it is a pain and should be automatic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've been running a VNC server on quite a few servers which have GUIs running inside of them for the last five years. It's not ideal, the setup is a bit clunky and security wise it's not great (passwords are concatenated at 8 chars for instance) but if you don't require high security it might be a solution for you.

Comment: sounds kinda like what I have running now.  Also security is a problem on my system, i guess an open RDP connection exposed to the web isn't the best idea.

Comment: I ended up trying a VNC server, which I connect to via SSH tunnel.  I figured this was better security wise than a direct connection.

Answer (score 0):

I did some picking and ended up coming up with something that is better than what I had.  I set up the `tightvncserver` on the EC2 cloud server using the instructions from [this tutorial](http://www.vandorp.biz/2012/01/installing-a-lightweight-lxdevnc-desktop-environment-on-your-ubuntudebian-vps/#.U4GkRt8wGNA).

Then I was about to just connect to the `tightvncserver` throught an SSH tunnel, using the normal key-based connection.  In order to do this, after following the above tutorial, you can connect to the server via SSH, at the same time establishing the tunnel.

```
ssh -i KeyPair.pem user@<ec2-server-ip> -L 9000:localhost:5901
```

Then you need to start the desktop session, but typing the following in your SSH command-line connection:

```
tightvncserver :1
```

Then you just need to use any old VNC client to connect to port 9000 of localhost.  Remember the password is the VNC password, not the linux system password:

[image]

I like this much better then what I had because 1) there is only 1 desktop session that the VNC naturally re-connects to each time.  2) I don't need to open any ports besides the port for SSH.  Before I had opened a port for the RDP connection.  I closed that, and now just have the 1 port listening for SSH connections.